# how to use an Emit with a v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, emit, v-model

i am on Vue3, and i try to catch a value from the child to the parent.
So my code is :

On the parent :

```html
<template>
  <input-form v-model="valueSuperficie" label="Surface en m²" />
</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return {
      valueSuperficie = null,
    }
  }
</script>
```

and on the child i try to make an emit.

```html
<template>
  <input 
    v-on:change="$emit('userEntry', $event.target.valueInput)"
    v-model="userEntry"
  />
</template>
    
<script>
  data() {
    return {
      userEntry: this.valueInput,
    };
  },
  emits: ["userEntry"],
    
</script>
```

I know that my code is incorrect, what I would like is to succeed in storing the value of the child, namely userEntry in the data valueSuperficie of the parent.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In child component define a prop called `modelValue` and emit an event named `update:modelValue` :

```html
<template>
   <input 
      v-on:input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
      :value="modelValue"
/>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  props:{
     modelValue:String
    },
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
}
</script>
```

Comment: worth noting it doesn't have to be called `modelValue` but calling it something else requires you to specify the name as a parameter in the v-model binding

Comment: You're right I'll mention that later

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the child component name is `input-form`.
The parent should process the event the child is triggering using a callback function. That function would be a method that assigns the received value to the inner value called `valueSuperficie`.

So the parent should look like this:

```js
<template>
  <input-form @user-entry="onUserEntry" label="Surface en m²" />
</template>

<script>
   data() {
     return {
      valueSuperficie = null,
      }
   },
   methods: {
     onUserEntry(valueInput) {
       this.valueSuperficie = valueInput;
     }
   }
</script>
```